# Incompatible type of onMapReady() function

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I'm try to set my OnMapReadyCallback as get map Async argument. But android tell me that it require GoogleMap object, in the documentation onMapReady() is void. The code below

```
private void initilizeMap() {
    if (googleMap == null) {
        googleMap = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
                R.id.map)).getMapAsync(this);

        // check if map is created successfully or not
        if (googleMap == null) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                    "Sorry! unable to create maps", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
    map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
    map.setTrafficEnabled(true);
    map.setIndoorEnabled(true);
    map.setBuildingsEnabled(true);
    map.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`getMapAsync` doesn't return a `GoogleMap` object ([documentation](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/MapFragment#getMapAsync(com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback))). You can initialize your `googleMap` object like this:

```
private void initilizeMap() {
    ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
            R.id.map)).getMapAsync(this);
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
    googleMap = map;
    map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
    map.setTrafficEnabled(true);
    map.setIndoorEnabled(true);
    map.setBuildingsEnabled(true);
    map.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
}
```

Comment: clearly an answer , but OP don't know what he wants, but to get the map reference and call async function too so all little more info about that would boost your post too dude +1

Answer (score 0):

you can try to this code.

```
 private void initilizeMap() {
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    // check if map is created successfully or not
    if (googleMap == null) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "Sorry! unable to create maps", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
    }
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
    googleMap = map;
    map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
    map.setTrafficEnabled(true);
    map.setIndoorEnabled(true);
    map.setBuildingsEnabled(true);
    map.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(true);
}
```

Comment: an explanation would be helpful for OP dude